# State variable not updated after DelegateCall

Tags: smart-contract-wallets, delegatecall, fallback-function, state-variable

I deployed two contracts 'WalletLibrary' and 'Wallet': most of the functions in Wallet delegateCall() the functions from WalletLibrary. I want to recreate an Attack, where I call the initWallet() function from WalletLibrary by triggering the fallback function from Wallet. However when I do that, the Owner in Wallet is updated to my address, but the one in WalletLibrary is not. Further the owner of WalletLibrary is 0000000000000000 when deployed (did I do sth wrong with deploying maybe?), I would expect the owner should be the address I deployed it from.

From my understanding, when I update some variable in Wallet, then it should also be updated in WalletLibrary, because delegateCall() preserves context, right? My Question is, why it does not work. Please tell me, if I got something wrong. Hope anyone can help.

Below, the code for both contracts...

WalletLibrary.sol:

```js
    pragma solidity ^0.5.4;
    
    contract WalletLibrary {
        address walletLibrary; 
        address payable owner;
        address payable student;
    
        event LogValue(uint256 exitcode,uint256 amount);
    
        function initWallet(address payable _owner) public payable {
        owner = _owner;
        }
    
        function getOwner() public view returns (address payable) {
        return owner;
        }
    
        function changeOwner(address payable new_owner) public returns (bool success) {
        if (msg.sender == owner) {
            owner = new_owner;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        }
    
        function withdraw(uint256 amount) public returns (bool success) {
            if (msg.sender == owner) {
                return owner.send(amount);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    
        function () external payable {
            emit LogValue(200,msg.value);
        }
    }
```

Wallet.sol:

```js
    pragma solidity ^0.5.4;
    
    contract Wallet {
        address walletLibrary;
        address payable owner;
        address payable student;
    
        event LogValue(uint256 exitcode,uint256 amount);
    
        // constructor, called once when this contract is created 
        constructor(address payable _student, address lib) public payable {
            student = _student;  
            walletLibrary = lib; // hardcode lib address at deploy time
            // init the owner with the respective lib contract
            walletLibrary.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("initWallet(address)", msg.sender));
        }
    
        function getOwner() public view returns (address payable) {
            return owner;
        } 
    
        function getWalletLibrary() public view returns (address) {
            return walletLibrary;
        }
    
        function withdraw(uint256 amount) public returns (bool) {
            (bool success, bytes memory data) = walletLibrary.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("withdraw(uint256)", amount));
            if ( success ) {
                emit LogValue(200,amount);
            } else {
                emit LogValue(401,amount);
            }
            return success;
        }
    
        function changeOwner(address payable new_owner) public returns (bool) {
            (bool success, bytes memory data) = walletLibrary.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("changeOwner(address)", new_owner));
            return success;
        }
    
        function getStudent() public view returns (address) {
            return student;
        }
    
        // fallback function gets called if no other function matches call
        function () external payable {
            emit LogValue(301,msg.value);
            require( tx.origin == student ); 
            walletLibrary.delegatecall(msg.data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use delegatecall then it will execute the **code** of the **target** in the **context** of the **caller**. That means when your `Wallet` contract used delegatecall to your `WalletLibrary` it will use the code from the library but the state (e.g. `owner`, `student`, etc) from the `Wallet`.

Therefore to change the state of the `WalletLibrary` you would have to directly interact with that contract.

A detailed introduction for delegatecalls can be found here: https://medium.com/coinmonks/delegatecall-calling-another-contract-function-in-solidity-b579f804178c

The `owner` of your `WalletLibrary` is `0x0000...0000` because you do not have any constructor, therefore the owner is not intialized. In your `Wallet` you call the `initWallet` function to do so, therefore the `Wallet` owner is set to `msg.sender`.